# Spark-Scala: Map the first element of list with every other element of list when lists are of varying length

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapping, rdd

I have dataset of the following type in a textile:

```
1004,bb5469c5|2021-09-19 01:25:30,4f0d-bb6f-43cf552b9bc6|2021-09-25 05:12:32,1954f0f|2021-09-19 01:27:45,4395766ae|2021-09-19 01:29:13,
1018,36ba7a7|2021-09-19 01:33:00,
1020,23fe40-4796-ad3d-6d5499b|2021-09-19 01:38:59,77a90a1c97b|2021-09-19 01:34:53,
1022,3623fe40|2021-09-19 01:33:00,
1028,6c77d26c-6fb86|2021-09-19 01:50:50,f0ac93b3df|2021-09-19 01:51:11,
1032,ac55-4be82f28d|2021-09-19 01:54:20,82229689e9da|2021-09-23 01:19:47,
```

I read the file using `sc.textFile` which returns an RDD of type `Array[String]` after which I perform the operations `.map(x=>x.substring(1,x.length()-1)).map(x=>x.split(",").toList)`

After `split.toList` I want to map the first element of each of the lists obtained to every other element of the list for which I use  `.map(x=>(x(0),x(1))).toDF("c1","c2")`

This works fine for those lists which have only one value after split but skips on all other elements of the lists having more than one value for obvious reasons. For eg:
 `.map(x=>(x(0),x(1)))` returns `[1020,23fe40-4796-ad3d-6d5499b|2021-09-19 01:38:59]` but skips out on the third element here `77a90a1c97b|2021-09-19 01:34:53`

How can I write a map function which returns `[1020,23fe40-4796-ad3d-6d5499b|2021-09-19 01:38:59], [1020,77a90a1c97b|2021-09-19 01:34:53]`  given that all the lists created using `.map(x=>x.split(",").toList)` are of varying lengths (have varying number of elements)?

Comment: Have you looked at the `tail` method? It gives you all the elements of a list excepted the first one.

Comment: But I need the first element. That is the primary key. I need to map the key with all elements of a list to get a unique key-value pair. Like in the example - 1020 is the primary key with 2 subsequent values. It should be paired with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noted the ',' at the end of the file, but `split` ignores nulls.

The solution is as follows, just try it and you will see it works:

```
// x._n cannot work here initially.
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/FileStore/tables/oddfile_01.txt")
val rdd2 = rdd.map(line => line.split(','))
val rdd3 = rdd2.map(x => (x(0), x.tail.toList)) 
val rdd4 = rdd3.flatMap{case (x, y) => y.map((x, _))}
rdd4.collect
```

Cardinality does change in this approach though.